# Asynctask lifecycle inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Could anyone explain what does exactly happens (lifecycle of `Asynctask`) if for example I have and `Activity` with a `Fragment` and from this `Fragment` I execute an `Asynctask` where on the `onPreExecute` I start displaying a `ProgressDialog` and at some point I close the app while the `Asynctask` is still running?

As far as I've checked the `Fragment` doesn't call `onDetach` nor `onDestroy` and the `Asynctask` doesn't reach the `onPostExecute` method or `onCancelled`

Comment: let me know your question Clearly.. You need to know.. how fragment lifecycle will work ? or Asynctask?

Comment: can you post your Asynctask code and how your executing

Answer (score 3):

If i am not wrong you are familiar with lifecycle of an AsyncTask. If not, refer

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

To answer why onPostExecute method is not called when we exit the app while the progress bar is still running, I would say it is because, AT holds a reference to the Activity/Context which would be destroyed by the time progress bar decides it's job is done(bg task/thread).

Very useful blog on how to handle ATs wrt fragments and activities by Alex Lockwood.

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you set setRetainInstance(true) in your fragment, whenever you start asynctask inside a fragment with setRetainInstance as true the task will continue to run in background without interrupt which is not in the case of an activity

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that AsyncTask.doInBackground() has been completed. Or, what is more possible, your main thread is stuck somewhere as AsyncTask.onPostExecute() must be executed in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you are speaking about, the Fragment methods "onPause()" and "onStop()" will be called (besides of the ones of the Activity which contains the given Fragment).

As those methods are being called, you should react according to what you want to do in the AsyncTask.

If that's not the case, refer to the link given by **#stack_ved**.

Anyway, if you want to do any kind of load inside a Fragment, I strongly recommend you to use "Loaders" or "AsyncTaskLoader".

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Comment: So now my doubt is why it seem to be a memory leak due to the progress dialog when for example, I display a ProgressDialog in a fragment or activity and I don't dismiss it, but it doesn't seem to happen if I have a fragment with an AsynctTask in it which dismisses the dialog on the onPostExecute method and appearently is never called because I close the app before the AT finishes.

Comment: The problem is that AsyncTask is not linked with the Android lifecycle (so you will have to manage for the AsncTask all the events happening in both, the Activity and the Fragment). That's why I recommend you using Loaders.